# Split screen into four equal parts/boxes, but stack the boxes below a specified width

Tags: css, responsive-design

I can split the screen into four boxes, that is not too difficult. Currently I have a ul with four list items. Each list item is 50% width, 50% height, then they are absolutely positioned. Here is the CSS I'm using:

```
nav {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
    nav ul {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    nav li.menu-section {
        height: 50%;
        width: 50%;
        text-align: center;
    }
    nav li.menu-section.top {
        top: 0;
    }
    nav li.menu-section.bottom {
        top: 50%;
    }
    nav li.menu-section.left {
        left: 0;
    }
    nav li.menu-section.right {
        left: 50%;
    }
```

Now the tricky part. To make it responsive I'd like to, below a certain width, stack the sections. So each li would be width: 100% and display under each other. However the height must remain consistent. Obviously this poses a problem if the height remains at 50%, as then the resulting total height is 200% causing a scrolling issue!

I'd preferably like to solve using CSS alone, but I'm already using plenty of JavaScript, so if I have to use a bit of JS then no problemo!

Comment: Needs more explanation and a fiddle because there's too many ways to interpret what you want.

Comment: The height must remain consistent with what?